# Can you detect light that is never going to reach you?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, photons

If you have light that is going away from you in exactly the opposite direction then I assume that you are never going to be able to detect it, because you can't catch up to it.

But if you have light that is going in any other direction, could one detect it?

Comment: @pela I mean without any light reaching you. Without scattering. Light that doesn't go in the opposite direction could be reached with something that has less than light speed.

Comment: You can never catch up with light. Light always moves with the speed of light ($c$) with respect to _any_ observer. No matter how much you accelerate, light will not even move slower away from you, but _still_ move with $v=c$. That's relativity for ya. If you want to detect the light, you must "catch" it with something that is already placed in its direction of motion, e.g. a photodetector or your eye.

Comment: If your friend drives a car at 100km/h and you drive a car at say 80km/h it is still possible to catch up with your friend by taking a shorter path?

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood you. If light is traveling in a direction not _exactly_ toward you, but not too far from you either, you may "catch" it. E.g. if a laser 300,000 km from you points one meter to the left of you, and it starts shining at the same time as you start walking left at 1 m/s, then yes, you can catch it. I don't know if that is what you mean; I don't really understand the headline of your question. If the light never reaches you, you cannot detect it (by definition of "reach" and "detect", I suppose).

Comment: -1. Unclear what you are asking. If the light never reaches you, how do you think you might detect it? Are you asking if it is possible to catch up with the light? ... Also, what do you think the answer is and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can detect the light, it means someone can transmit information to you. So in the theory of special relativity, as long as your world line can intercept the light cone, you will be able to detect it. Otherwise, you won't. Note that we assume no scattering of light in this case, which might redirect some photons towards your world line.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will try a scenario, may be more knowledgeable users can correct.

Suppose an observer is falling into a black hole. Before reaching the photon sphere, if the observer sends a light beam just at the right time and in the right direction, then it is possible that the light beam becomes part of photon sphere and at the same time the observer happens to be at the photon sphere.

A long shot, but seems a possibility.

This is revised answer. Previous answer, as pointed out by annav was incorrect and so, has been changed.

Comment: I am not the one downvoting, but you have to tie up the answer to the question, I think the OP is talking of light starting from his location.HYW has given the general answer

Comment: @annav: OK, I will delete the answer.

Comment: far fetched but ok, imo

Answer (score -4):

No, in fact due to Hubble expansion certain parts of the universe are moving away Pretty fast therefore once they start moving away even faster than the speed of light then the light will never reach us. This is all theoretical though.

Comment: This is wrong. We easily see galaxies move away from us at velocities greater than the speed of light. That's _general_ relativity for ya.

Comment: For an explanation, see e.g. [this answer](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19909/will-we-start-seeing-galaxies-disappear-due-to-universe-expansion/19910#19910).